# Don't change the default internal input device

Tags: microphone, speakers

When I pair with my bluetooth speaker, the input gets changed to Line In

Is it possible to have it not do that? To always keep the internal microphone selected...

Comment: We need bit more info and some clarity. The Bluetooth speaker is not a Input source it is a output! So we need more info to track why is it changing your Input source to line in? What is your BT speaker model/make? Is there a Console report on the event. What does your about this mac show in the profile for it?

Comment: Speaker is Big Turtle Shell (http://www.outdoortechnology.com/Shop/Big-Turtle-Shell/) and it has a microphone for hands-free calling...

Comment: There is your reason why it switches the Input source. So the question is how to disable the BT microphone? Anything in the BT manuals ?

Comment: No, it's not possible on the speaker side that's why I wanted to know if OSX can be persuaded to ignore this MIC when I use the device as speakers only...